# unshare/isolate mount namespace

Tags: linux-kernel, namespaces, filesystems, linux-containers

I'm trying to set up a linux `container` with isolated mount namespace using `unshare` tool from `util-linux` package :

```
% sudo unshare -m -f /bin/bash
```

So I'm expecting that bash will be launched in a namespace, where the mount namespace, i.e. filesystems, will be completely isolated form the host one, however I still can modify the host FS (create/delete files on the host FS). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mount [namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) only creates a separate mount tree by copying the parent tree.

You still have to remount the file systems as read-only, unmount them, mount a tmpfs over them or [pivot_root](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html) into a clean tree to prevent access. Switching to an umapped user via user namespaces can help to some extent but it won't prevent access to world-readable/writable files.

If you need to setup more complex namespace environments - containers basically - you can use [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) or [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) to automate those tasks based on configuration files. [systemd-nspawn](http://systemd-nspawn) provides some intermediate featureset between accessing the primitives directly, as unshare does, and container runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that mount namespace is isolated because mount/unmount in the namespace does not have impact on the host FS. So I think modifying FS is another issue, probably related to userns, but not fully sure about this.